# Validation does not work with Partial<DTO> - NestJS

Tags: javascript, nestjs, class-validator, server-side-validation

I want to apply server-side validation on my CRUD API. The entity in question is called `Employee`. I am using an `employee.dto` (shown below) for the create and update endpoints.

The class-validator package works fine on the `create` method but ignores all rules in the DTO when I use it with `Partial<EmployeeDTO>` in the update method.

Please use the code below for reference.

## Packages

```
"class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
"class-validator": "^0.10.0",
```

## Employee DTO

```
import { IsString, IsNotEmpty, IsEmail, IsEnum } from 'class-validator';

import { EmployeeRoles } from '../../entities/employee.entity';

export class EmployeeDTO {
  @IsString()
  @IsEmail()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  email: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  username: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  fullName: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEnum(EmployeeRoles)
  role: string;
}
```

## Employee Controller

```
import {
  Controller,
  Param,
  Post,
  Body,
  Put,
  UsePipes,
} from '@nestjs/common';

import { EmployeeDTO } from './dto/employee.dto';
import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';
import { ValidationPipe } from '../shared/pipes/validation.pipe';

@Controller('employee')
export class EmployeeController {
  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

  @Post()
  @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
  addNewEmployee(@Body() data: EmployeeDTO) {
    return this.employeeService.create(data);
  }

  @Put(':id')
  @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
  updateEmployee(@Param('id') id: number, @Body() data: Partial<EmployeeDTO>) {
    return this.employeeService.update(id, data);
  }
}
```

## Possible Solution

I work around I can think of is creating separate DTOs for `create` and `update` methods, but I don't like the idea of repeating the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this answer, I'll take a guess and assume that you use the `ValidationPipe` provided in the [NestJS' documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#class-validator), or a close derivative.

Your `updateEmployee` method's argument `data` type is `Partial`, which doesn't emit any type metadata. for the `ValidationPipe` to instantiate it using the `class-transformer` module, resulting in the `class-validator` module to validate a plain object, and not an `EmployeeDTO`.

For the validation to work, the type of the `data` argument should be a class.
You could either make separate DTOs to create and update your entity, or use [validation groups](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-groups) if you want to keep a single class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I plan to integrate Swagger in the future as well. Which approach would be better, having separate DTOs or keep a single class?

Comment: and Yes, I am using `Validation Pipe`

Comment: For Swagger, I think having separate DTOs would make for a clearer documentation.

Comment: Yes, I had the same thought, although it repeats a lot of the code. Thanks.

Comment: Even though it duplicates some code, IMO it allows you to have better comprehension and separation of concerns. Also I assume that when you create an employee, some attributes of your DTO class are required, while when you update it, they're optional.

Comment: do seprate DTO is good approach but about if my dto is large and i dont want to write again this  
DTO for update please see my issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78238231/i-got-an-error-for-partialtype-is-not-working-for-updatedto/78238950#78238950

Answer (score 30):

In order to achieve partial validation, you can use `PartialType` utility function. You can read about it here:
https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types#partial

You would need to create another class:

```
export class UpdateEmployeeDTO extends PartialType(EmployeeDTO) {}
```

and then in your controller, you need to replace the type of `@Body data Partial<EmployeeDTO>` to `UpdateEmployeeDto`. It should look like this:

```
@Patch(':id')
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
updateEmployee(@Param('id') id: number, @Body() data: UpdateEmployeeDTO) {
    return this.employeeService.update(id, data);
}
```

Please keep in mind that you should import `PartialType` from `@nestjs/mapped-types` not from `@nestjs/swagger` like suggested in the documentation. More about this can be found [here](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/1795)

Comment: Could you please add to your answer that `PartialType` needs to be imported from `@nestjs/mapped-types`? The documentation was misleading. Also the `updateEmployee` function should be PATCH not PUT. PUT is meant to replace everything and PATCH to update only specific values.

Comment: @Mick thanks for the suggestions. 
I have left `Put` because it was originally used in the question, but you are right - we should use `Patch` because `PartialType` allows to edit only a part of the requested object not necessarily whole object. I have changed that, thanks.

I wonder if `@nestjs/mapped-types` is a correct import. Why do you think the documentation was misleading? I have wrote few sample unit tests and verified that `PartialType` from `@nestjs/swagger` package (which is suggested in the documentation) is working as expected as well.

Comment: It does not work with `@nestjs/swagger`, only if you actually use swagger. Otherwise it should be `@nestjs/mapped-types`. It is not documented but there is an open issue to documentate that: https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/1795

Comment: Thanks @Mick I didn't know about that. I have put information about this in my post.

Comment: It is now documented here: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#mapped-types -> There is even a third library `@nestjs/graphql` which needs to be used when using graphql.

Comment: Seems that `@nestjs/swagger` is fine now except when in combination with `@ValidateNested`. With `@nestjs/mapped-types` all is fine.

Comment: i have the same issue about the PartialType i'm trying import from both @nest/swagger and @nestjs/mapped-types here is problem url-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78238231/i-got-an-error-for-partialtype-is-not-working-for-updatedto/78238950#78238950

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this exact issue and would like to share some discoveries as well as a solution.

Let's pretend we have this class:

```
User {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;
  @IsOptional()
  nickname?: string;
}
```

On POST you want all validations to apply. On PATCH (or PUT) you want only validations to apply for properties that are specified. Well, POST is no problem, in the controller do:

```
@Body() params: User
```

But, PATCH (or PUT) is problematic because there is no way to handle partial validations out of the box without applying it universally.

Here are some solutions I explored:

### Solution 1: PartialType [ FAIL ]

```
import { OmitType, PartialType } from '@nestjs/swagger';

UpdateUser extends PartialType(User) {}
```

Then, in the controller:

```
@Body() params: UpdateUser,
```

Using NestJS' PartialType does not override the class validator annotations on the parent class. So, if you have a `@IsNotEmpty()` on the parent class it will still make it required.

### Solution 2: Partial [ FAIL ]

In the controller:

```
@Body() params: Partial<User>
```

None of the class validator annotations apply. This is because generics are not supported, as explained elsewhere.

### Solution 3: Validation within controller [ PASS, not recommended ]

In the controller:

```
@Body() params: any
```

Then, in the controller method call class validator's `validate()` directly with something like:

```
const transformedValue = plainToClassFromExist(new User(), params);
const errors = validate(transformedValue, {
  skipUndefinedProperties: true
});
```

The magic here is `skipUndefinedProperties`. If the property does not exist (ie is undefined) then class validator will not validate it. Note that @IsDefined() bypasses this.

This would work, but will result in lots of duplicate code.

### Solution 4: Use a custom decorator [ PASS, RECOMMENDED ]

Create a decorator called `PartialBody` that reads the type information from an enhancer and then runs validations, see https://gist.github.com/josephdpurcell/d4eff886786d58f58b86107c0947e19e as an example.

Make sure validateCustomDecorators=false in your global validation pipe.

Now, there are a few variations of how to use it:

#### Variation 1: Pass the type [ PASS, RECOMMENDED ]

In the controller:

```
@PartialBody(User) params: Partial<User>
```

When `PartialBody` runs it will retrieve the type from the passed argument. This will only validate properties that exist, and will ensure `params` is a partial of User. Huzzah!

#### Variation 2: Use partial [ FAIL ]

In the controller:

```
@PartialBody() params: Partial<User>
```

This fails because generics aren't supported. When the `PartialBody` decorator logic is run it has access to no type information.

#### Variation 3: Use class [ FAIL ]

In the controller:

```
@PartialBody() params: User
```

While this would perform partial validations just like Variation 1, it fails because `params` would be seen as a full type instead of a partial type. While writing code your editor would think that all properties are there when they may not be.

#### Variation 4: Extend PartialType [ PASS ]

Create a new type with PartialType:

```
import { PartialType } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class PartialUser extends PartialType(User) {}
```

In the controller:

```
@PartialBody() params: PartialUser
```

This works just like Variation 1, but you have to create an additional class. This may be desired if you wish to override class validator checks by overwriting the properties and redeclaring decorators.

Comment: Where can the @PartialBody be found? Nest.js doesn't have any entry in the documentation.

Comment: You answer is great. I've tried to apply on my code, but the problem is on the Swagger we do not have the required body section.

Comment: @jiko Unfortunately I didn't see your comment until now, I've updated the answer to clarify where PartialBody is found, it's here: https://gist.github.com/josephdpurcell/d4eff886786d58f58b86107c0947e19e

Comment: @CarlosQuerioz thanks! I didn't explore swagger compatibility with these solutions. If there is an improvement I'm happy to edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This article opened my mind and gave me a better understanding: https://medium.com/fusionworks/api-payloads-validation-and-transformation-in-nestjs-5022ce4df225

It all started because I am lazy and don't want to write multiple classes (a  create DTO and an update DTO). Plus, you make one change in one class, you have to remember make the change in the other one.

As a result, my updateDTO extends my createDTO & my initial approach was with `PartialType` imported from `@nestjs/mapped-types`.

Given the following example:

```
export class CreateEmployeeDTO {
    // might wanna do this if you want to take an updateDto and transform to an createDto
    @Exclude()
  id?: number;
  
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  username: string;
  
  @IsSring()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;
  
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  role: string;
}
```

For the UpdateEmployeeDTO I extend it using `OmitType` instead of `PartialType`, because I am assuming when I am updating the Employee:

- I need to pass an id of the employee
- I might not wanna change the password, make it optional
- I want to have the client pass the username & role all the time

Therefore, my UpdateEmployeeDTO looks as such:

```
export class UpdateEmployeeDTO extends OmitType(CreateEmployeeDTO, ['id', 'password']) {
    @IsNumber()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  id: number;
  
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  password: string;
}
```

The second array passed to the `OmitType` are the properties omitted from CreateEmployeeDTO.

Therefore, on update if I update the employee and not give it an username or role, my ValidationPipe will produce the appropriate error according to class-validator.

As a result, with the respect to the question, all rules in the (create) DTO will not be ignored.

Read the article above, very well written.